# Differences when using grep in terminal and :grep in vim

Tags: vim, grep

I am seeing differences when using `grep` in terminal and `:grep` in vim

The former, `grep -ri --include *.sh backup` returns results.

The latter, `:grep -ri --include *.sh backup`  does not.

Any thoughts?

Edit 1:
`:set grepprg` returns `grepprg=grep -n $* /dev/null`

Edit 2: My only grep alias is `alias grep='grep --color=auto'`

Comment: Different working directory?

Comment: Does your `grep` command really work? You aren't specifying a target for `grep`. You need something like `grep -ri --include *.sh backup .`. Also you may want to check out [`git grep`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)/[ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)/[ack](http://beyondgrep.com/).

Comment: My grep command really works. I believe the directory I am in is being used.

Comment: Posted answer below.

Comment: Looks like you are using a version of GNU grep 2.11+. [Where does grep -r search by default?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38793). Which defaults to using the current working directory if using the `-r` flag.

Comment: @PeterRincker Should I not be relying on this capability?

Comment: That really depends on your environment(s). If you are often working working on older machines or more unix complaint boxes then you may want to change your habits. Otherwise I wouldn't worry about it. However if you do find yourself doing a bunch of recursive grepping then I would recommend learning `git grep`, ag, and/or ack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing my `grepprg` value fixed my issue

In my `~/.vimrc`

```
" Grep settings
set grepprg=grep\ -n\ $*
```

The default value of `grepprg=grep -n $* /dev/null` was using /dev/null as the directory.

Comment: For those wondering, the reason why the default appends `/dev/null` to the grepprg; this is needed to force the grep commands to 
print the name of the file in which a match is found, if only one filename 
is specified.