# What does `$*`(a dollar sign followed by a star) mean in the default setting of `grepprg` in vim?

Tags: shell, vim, grep, metacharacters

In a vanilla vim on Mac, when I type `:set grepprg?`, it returns the following:

`grepprg=grep -n $* /dev/null`.

I understand what `-n` and `/dev/null` means,
thanks to an old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907418/2271797).
I also understand what `$` and `*` means individually.
However, I am not sure what to make of `$*`.
I tried to look it up in the vim doc,
but all that I could find was

> The placeholder "$*" is allowed to specify where the arguments will be included.

I sense that I am missing some important connection here.
I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me
how `$*` works as a placeholder.

Update:
Thanks to the detailed explanation from @romainl,
I realized that I was misinterpreting `$*` as regex,
whereas they are part of the convention in shell script.
In fact, there already exists [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413848/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script)
about this particular convention.
Silly me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of explanation is needed beyond what you have already quoted:

> The placeholder "$*" is allowed to specify where the arguments will be included.

`$*` is just a placeholder and it works like all placeholders: before being actually sent to the shell, the command is built out of `&grepprg` and `$*`, *if present*, is replaced by any pattern, filename, flags, etc. provided by the user.

Say you want to search for `foo\ bar` in all JavaScript files under the current directory. The command would be:

```
:grep 'foo\ bar' *.js
```

After you press `<CR>`, Vim grabs any argument you gave to `:grep`, in this case:

```
'foo\ bar' *.js
```

then, if there is a `$*` in `&grepprg`, it is replaced with the given argument:

```
grep -n 'foo\ bar' *.js /dev/null
```

or, if there is no `$*` in `&grepprg`, the given argument is appended to it, and only then sends the whole command to a shell.

`$*` means "in this command, I specifically want the user-provided arguments to appear here".

As for the meaning of `$*`… `$` and `*` have no intrinsic meaning and `$*` could have been `$$$PLACEHOLDER$$$` or anything. `$*` may have been chosen because it is used in shell script to represent all the arguments given to a function or script, which is somewhat close in meaning to what is happening in `&grepprg` with `$*`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I think I was overthinking about the `$*`.  When I said "I understand what they mean" in my original post, I was interpreting them individually as `$` --- end of line and `*` --- zero or multiple instances of the character to its left, as in regex.  But apparently I was not aware of the conventional use of `$*` in shell script.